# Python boto - How can I get allocation id of elastic ip

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

When I use boto(python sdk for aws) to assign elastic ip to my instance in vpc, it reported the following error:

```
    <Response>
      <Errors>
         <Error>
           <Code>InvalidParameterCombination</Code>
           <Message>You must specify an allocation id when mapping an address to a network interface</Message>
    </Error>
    </Errors>
    <RequestID>d0f95756-c36f-417a-9fa9-1158c4aa19e9</RequestID>
</Response>
```

But I found nothing about allocation id in ec2-medata.

Anybody know how can I get allocation id from API?

I already seen it in console:

`try:
        conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(zone, aws_access_key_id='a-id', aws_secret_access_key='s-id',debug=2)
        conn.associate_address(allow_reassociation=True, public_ip=kw['ip'], network_interface_id=nid, dry_run=True)`

Comment: try:
        conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(zone, aws_access_key_id='aid', aws_secret_access_key='sid',debug=2)
        if kw.has_key('type') and kw['type'] == 'elastic':
            conn.associate_address(allow_reassociation=True, public_ip=kw['ip'], network_interface_id=nid, dry_run=True)
        else:
            conn.assign_private_ip_addresses(allow_reassignment=True, network_interface_id=nid, private_ip_addresses=kw['ip'])

Comment: That's not readable - please add it to your question, formatted etc.

Comment: See code example here: http://engineerwithoutacause.com/amazon-ec2-deployment-with-boto.html

Answer (score 2):

If you use `get_all_addresses` it should return a list of `Address` objects which have an `allocation_id` attribute associated with them.  The `allocation_id` will be non-None for any addresses that are associated with a VPC.

```
import boto.ec2
c = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
addresses = c.get_all_addresses()
for addr in addresses:
    print('%s - %s' % (addr.public_ip, addr.allocation_id)
```

Does that help?